# What order of magnitude should I expect the parasitic capacitance to be for a solderless breadboard?

Tags: breadboard, parasitic-capacitance

I'm trying to account for some error in measurements for a circuit I have produced physically and simulated in spice. The only suspect seems to be the solderless breadboard as the error seems to increase with frequency.

Comment: Should be fairly easy to calculate.

Comment: Should be a datasheet spec.

Comment: Bigger problem in my experience is contact *resistance*. You can end up with surprisingly high resistance sometimes - but only sometimes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

2-3pF row to row, and 20pf rail to rail, but checkout this video...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6GIscUsnlM0&feature=youtu.be

Probably a bigger issue with BBS is often the flying leads and longer legs on resistors etc. The extra inductance will also give you issues at higher frequencies. That and fairly high point contact resistance.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany yes it surprised me a bit too. I think the bigger issue with BBs is all the extra lead inductances from having longer leads on the flying components and wires.

Comment: if you foil-coat the bottom sticker and trim down leads so that components are flush against the board, they perform a lot better.